# Wordpress listing post categories as a tag attribute

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, categories

If you want to have post categories listed as links, you got it covered. I have a problem that I want to have a list of post categories space seperated as a value of div's data-id attribute.

This is how my current loop looks like:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $post_id = the_ID(); $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id ); ?>
        <div class="box" data-id=" <?php foreach($post_categories as $c){ echo $c; } ?>     ">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(200,200) ); ?>
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="blur"></div>
                <div class="caption-text">
                    <h3><a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

unfortunately the result of that looks like [Loop visual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOox5.jpg)

I guess it's a no-brainer for some of you but I just can't make it right. thanks for having a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_the_ID()` to return the ID:

```
wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() );
```